# IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext Could not open ServletContext resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know this question was asked many times, but I don't get the reason of the exception:

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">


    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>web/WEB-INF/hello-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                web/WEB-INF/hello-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`hello-servlet.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ua.epam.spring.hometask" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The exception is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/web/WEB-INF/hello-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/web/WEB-INF/hello-servlet.xml]
My project structure is:
```

[image]

**Question**:

Please, help me to find out what is wrong?

Comment: put all that is inside the `web` folder in `src\main\webapp`, in your web.xml remove the `web/` prefix. Also don't load the configuration as you do now, you are basically loading your application twice!

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for answer! Why I load my application twice?

Comment: Because of `<context-param>` and `<param-value>`?

Comment: Because of the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` loading the same configuration.